# How to access data submitted from a view within the controller?

Tags: php, codeigniter, scope, variable-assignment

I have a very small app, it requires an id, then updates a database table based on that id. The id is an input from the view.

Basically my DB (model) has `getAllProjects()` and `approveProject($id)`.

**Controller:**

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit ('No direct script access allowed');

class ApproveProject extends CI_Controller {

    public function index () {
        $this->loadView();
    }

    public function getData () {
        $this->load->model("db_Projects");
        $this->db_Projects->getAllProjects();

    }

    public function updateDB () {
        // how can I get this variable?
        $this->db_Projects->approveProject($toApprove); 
    }

    public function loadView() {
        $this->load->view("ViewProjectApproval");
    }
}

?>
```

**View:**

```
<html language="en">
<head>
    <title>Aprobare Proiect</title>
</head>
    <h1> Aprobare Proiect </h1>
<body>
<div id="container">

    <?php
        if (isset($_POST['projectSubmit']) && ($_POST['projectSubmit'] == "Submit")) 
        { 
            $toApprove= $_POST['projectId'];
        }
    ?>


    <form action ="updateDB" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="projectId">
        <input type="submit" name="projectSubmit" value="Submit">
    </form>


</div>

</body>
```

I have no idea if my view is good, or if it should be otherwise ... how can I send the ID to my controller ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are submitting the form using `POST` method so you can retrieve the variable from the `POST` inside your controller's method, like

```
$toApprove = $this->input->post('projectId');
```

So your method/function will look like something like this

```
public function updateDB () {
    if($this->input->post('projectId'))
    {
        $toApprove = $this->input->post('projectId');
        // load the model and call the method, like
        $this->load->model('model_name');
        $model_name->method_name($toApprove);
    }
}
```

**Update:**
Your form's `action` doean't seem right, try this (controller_name/method_name)

```
<form action ="<?php echo site_url('ApproveProject/updateDB') ?>" method="post">
```

Comment: I tried this, did not work. So I commented `updateDB` and left an `echo "Test";` however that did not show up. Any idea, should I post the updated code just in case ?

Comment: Found the problem: It never enters the if clause

Comment: I think to remember Code Igniter destroys the superglobals, so accessing them in the controller doesn't work without some extra configuration. But they might have changed that with CI 2.

Comment: Yes, that last update did it, thank you! I think I forgot to load the model ?

Comment: you should consider loading models,helpers,library in a constructor function(at controller) , instead of the time when needed. Create a __construct() function at controller and load the models there.